Why can I not download the "granulator" package in R version 4.3.1?
I need to download the "granulator" package, but I am receiving this error message:
configure: error: GDALAllRegister not found in libgdal.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘sf’
*removing ‘/sfs/qumulo/qhome/guw3qk/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/sf’
ERROR: dependency ‘sf’ is not available for package ‘epiR’
*removing ‘/sfs/qumulo/qhome/guw3qk/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/epiR’
ERROR: dependency ‘epiR’ is not available for package ‘granulator’
*removing ‘/sfs/qumulo/qhome/guw3qk/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/granulator’
The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpdoK0W8/downloaded_packages’
Installation paths not writeable, unable to update packages
  path: /sfs/applications/202312/software/standard/mpi/gcc/11.4.0/openmpi/4.1.4/R/4.3.1/lib64/R/library
  packages:
    BH, bnlearn, brew, brio, callr, checkmate, cli, codetools, commonmark, data.table, deldir, desc,
    digest, dotCall64, dplyr, e1071, evaluate, fansi, farver, ff, fs, ggplot2, glue, GSA, gtable,
    gtools, interp, jsonlite, lattice, lifecycle, logspline, lpSolve, maps, markdown, MatrixModels,
    matrixStats, mgcv, mlbench, munsell, nlme, pixmap, pkgbuild, pkgload, plotrix, pls, pROC, processx,
    progress, ps, Rcpp, RcppArmadillo, RcppEigen, rJava, rlang, rlecuyer, rprojroot, rstudioapi, scales,
    segmented, sp, stringi, stringr, testthat, tidyselect, timeDate, vctrs, waldo, withr, xfun
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages(...) :
  installation of package ‘sf’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages(...) :
  installation of package ‘epiR’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages(...) :
  installation of package ‘granulator’ had non-zero exit status

Here is how I am attempting to download "granulator":
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("granulator")

The way I am interpreting the error message is that the packages "sf" and "epiR" need to also be installed in order for "granulator" to install -- however those packages will not download, either. For example, when I try to download "sf" I receive this message:
configure: error: GDALAllRegister not found in libgdal.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘sf’
* removing ‘/sfs/qumulo/qhome/guw3qk/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/sf’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sf’ had non-zero exit status

Is this a problem with the version of R I am operating in (4.3.1)? Unfortunately, I cannot change this version, as it is the only available R through my university's HPC.
Any suggestions would be HIGHLY appreciated!!!

Seems your problem starts with the installation of libgdal-dev (in Ubuntu) that isn't installed properly and has missing functions, i.e. GDALAllRegister. The R version doesn't matter. Talk to a sympathetic IT person and see if they can get GDAL lib and headers available, or build it on your own computer at home.

Maybe don't sleep on Installation paths not writeable, unable to update packages either.
